# how to fix this mysql community-> connector-python (python 3.4 is not installed)

Tags: python, mysql

[image]

I got this problem, how to fix it?
I have installed `python 3.6(64bit)` in my program `file/python36`
but still have this problem (in screenshoot)
I have downloaded `python 3.4` but link only give me source code, and I do know how to install it from source code

Comment: What package of Python 3.4 have you downloaded (provide full link). Are you on Windows ?

Comment: yes, im using win10 x64
- python which i've installed is 3.6, installed on c:program file/python36 is from official python sites.
- but here the link (python 3.4.7, its only give me source code)
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-347/
which i do know how to install it

Comment: Yup, this specific version does not seem to have Windows binaries, but there are plenty of other 3.4.x versions for windows: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ (reached from python.org > Downloads > Windows). I hope one of them will do for you.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the installer at:
https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

### Python 3.4.4 - 2015-12-21

Download [Windows x86 MSI installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.4/python-3.4.4.msi)

Download [Windows x86-64 MSI installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.4/python-3.4.4.amd64.msi)